JsonSchemaBuilder.FromType<T>().Build() does not execute IAttributeHandlers
I'm evaluating Json.Schema to generate json schemas from my typed objects in .net for sharing validation between client and server.
I have a super simple implementation called from a unit test.
var generator = new JsonSchemaBuilder();

AttributeHandler.AddHandler(new RequiredAttributeHandler());

var schema = generator.FromType<T>();

The RequiredAttributeHandler does not get called.
Am I doing it wrong?

What is the attribute that it's handling?  How is that attribute used on your model?  Have you read the docs or this example?

Some are owned by the code base some are from other libraries doing different things thought the system.
From the AttributeHandler.AddHandler I made the assumption that it would be called then an Attribute of TAttr is found based on IAttributeHandler.
But if it's only for Attributes that actually implements IAttributeHandler then I understand.

Attributes which implement IAttributeHandler<T> are automatically processed and don't need to be registered because the system inspects all of the attributes for the handler interface.  This is recommended if you're building your own attributes.
To handle attributes which don't implement IAttributeHandler<T>, you'll need to register the handler, otherwise the system can't find it.  This is recommended if you're using someone else's attributes.
In the case above, you have created a RequiredAttributeHandler.  I expect this might be for the [Required] attribute that's in _System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.  If that's the case, I'd recommend using another extension lib, JsonSchema.Net.Generation.DataAnnotations (docs), which provides handlers for (most of) the attributes in that namespace.
